# [move_base] make_plan service crashes, transport error

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, service, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

so I wrote a custom global planner plug-in and I have tested extensively, so I don't believe the error is there.  can launch rviz with move_base, costmap and a robot description. The issue arises as I want to call the service  make_plan() from the terminal. I am using the template completion provided by ROS.
The first time I call it, it gives me following error message but still compiles and publish the plan.

```
ERROR: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender,  unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

The second time I call the service move_base crashes and the following error message is displayed

```
[move_base-6] process has died [pid 10011, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/move_base/move_base __name:=move_base __log:=/home/rue011/.ros/log/06aca0b2-d577-11e7-bb08-d481d7bb040a/move_base-6.log]. log file: /home/rue011/.ros/log/06aca0b2-d577-11e7-bb08-d481d7bb040a/move_base-6*.log
```

Hope somebody can help, I have no Idea whats going wrong.

The log file ".../move_base-6*.log" is not not generated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276935/%5Bmove_base%5D-make_plan-service-crashes,-transport-error/) by [Fabs89](https://answers.ros.org/users/32631/fabs89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks ahendrix,

the issue was that I was calling a callback function while the action of move_base was still running, or rather by calling this callback and changing parameters of the current solver invoke a segmentation fault.

[CLOSED]

---

Originally posted by [Fabs89](https://answers.ros.org/users/32631/fabs89/) with karma: 26 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Exit code `-11` indicates that the move_base node died as a result of a segfault.

```
ERROR: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender,  unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

This transport error message indicates that there is something weird going on in the goal callback which is causing the returned data to be missing or corrupt somehow.

You should run move_base in a debugger like gdb to get a better idea of where it's crashing: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1